# GCP Dockerfile using Artifact Registry

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform

I have a question.

What's the best approach to building a Docker image using the pip artifact from the Artifact Registry?

I have a Cloud Build build that runs a Docker build, the only Dockerfile is `pip install -r requirements.txt`, one of the dependencies of which is the library located in the Artifact Registry.

When executing a stage with the image `gcr.io / cloud-builders / docker`, I get the error that my Artifact Registry is not accessible, which is quite logical. I have access only from the image performing the given step, not from the image that is being built in this step.

Any ideas?

Edit:

For now I will use Secret Manager to pass JSON key to my Dockerfile, but hope for better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use Cloud Build, you can forward the metadata server access through the Docker build process. It's [documented](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#network), but absolutely not clear (personally, the first time I made a mail to Cloud Build PM to ask him, and he send me the documentation link.)

Now, your docker build can access the metadata server and be authenticated with the [Cloud Build runtime service account](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#serviceaccount). It should make your process easiest.